# Python curve fitting problem with peaked and flat-top (super) gaussian signals

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, scipy-optimize

I have a standard gaussian function, that looks like this:

```
def gauss_fnc(x, amp, cen, sigma):
    return amp * np.exp(-(x - cen) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))
```

And I have a fit_gaussian function that uses scipy's curve_fit to fit my gauss_fnc:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_gaussian(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
    opt, cov = curve_fit(gauss_fnc, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean, sigma])
    values = gauss_fnc(x, *opt)
    return values, sigma, opt, cov
```

I can confirm that this works great if the data resembles a normal gaussian function, see example:

[image]

However if the signal is too peaked or too narrow, it won't work as expected.
Example of a peaked gaussian:

[image]

Here is an example of a flat-top or super gaussian:

[image]

Currently the flatter the gaussian becomes, more and more information is lost, due to gaussian cutting down the edges.
How can I improve the functions, or the curve fitting in order to be able to fit peaked and flat-top signals as well like in this picture:

[image]

Edit:

I provided a minimal working example to try this out:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout


def gauss_fnc(x, amp, cen, sigma):
    return amp * np.exp(-(x - cen) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

def fit_gauss(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))
    opt, cov = curve_fit(gauss_fnc, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean, sigma])
    vals = gauss_fnc(x, *opt)
    return vals, sigma, opt, cov


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.results = list()

        self.setWindowTitle('Gauss fitting')
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1280, 1024)
        self.setupLayout()

        self.raw_data1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)
        self.raw_data2 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 200, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)
        self.raw_data3 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)

        self.plot()

    def setupLayout(self):
        # Create figures
        self.fig1 = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100))
        self.fig1AX = self.fig1.figure.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
        self.fig1AX.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig1AX.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig1AX.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.fig1AX.yaxis.set_label_position("right")

        self.fig2 = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100))
        self.fig2AX = self.fig2.figure.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
        self.fig2AX.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig2AX.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig2AX.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.fig2AX.yaxis.set_label_position("right")

        self.fig3 = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100))
        self.fig3AX = self.fig3.figure.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
        self.fig3AX.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig3AX.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
        self.fig3AX.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.fig3AX.yaxis.set_label_position("right")

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.fig1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.fig2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.fig3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def plot(self):
        x = len(self.raw_data1)

        xvals, sigma, optw, covar = fit_gauss(range(x), self.raw_data1)
        self.fig1AX.clear()
        self.fig1AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data1)), self.raw_data1, 'k-')
        self.fig1AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data1)), xvals, 'b-', linewidth=2)
        self.fig1AX.margins(0, 0)
        self.fig1.figure.tight_layout()
        self.fig1.draw()

        xvals, sigma, optw, covar = fit_gauss(range(x), self.raw_data1)
        self.fig2AX.clear()
        self.fig2AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data2)), self.raw_data2, 'k-')
        self.fig2AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data2)), xvals, 'b-', linewidth=2)
        self.fig2AX.margins(0, 0)
        self.fig2.figure.tight_layout()
        self.fig2.draw()

        self.fig3AX.clear()
        self.fig3AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data3)), self.raw_data3, 'k-')
        self.fig3AX.plot(range(len(self.raw_data3)), xvals, 'b-', linewidth=2)
        self.fig3AX.margins(0, 0)
        self.fig3.figure.tight_layout()
        self.fig3.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Last picture is from [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Flat-Top-Pulse-Generation-by-the-Optical-Fourier-Palushani-Oxenl%C3%B8we/fa473737b25bbe2e8858528bc36860b07e3adaab).

Comment: Do you want to modify your fitted function or are you after a different fitting method that fits your original gaussian? These are two very different approaches.

Comment: If it's possible, I would like the original function to be modified in order to be universal. If it is not possible, a separate function for peaked gauissian and separate function for super gaussian is fine too.

Comment: Then it looks like you are after the [Generalized normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution).  There's an implementation in scipy: [`scipy.stats.gennorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gennorm.html)

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. Or if you implement it into my minimal working example, and post it as answer, I could give you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gaussian defined function for curve fit:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = range(21)
y_peak = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 200, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)
y_flat_top = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)


# define gauss function
def Gauss(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))


# fit function
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, x, y_peak)

# set data for curve plot
x_fit = np.linspace(0,21,1000)
y_fit = Gauss(x_fit, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
y_fit = Gauss(x_fit, max(y_flat_top) , popt[1], popt[2])

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y_peak, '.')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, '-', label='peak')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

With usage of Generalized normal distribution:
It is hard to fit. You can play with bounds and try to add some additional parameters to function to get better fit. Another option is to use [differential evolution algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) to find best fit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


# set data
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 20)
y_peak = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 200, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)
y_flat_top = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int)
y = y_peak

# define generalized normal distribution
def general_norm(x, gamma, beta):
    value = (beta/(2*gamma*(1/beta)))*np.exp(-np.abs(x)**beta)
    return value


# set bounds
bounds_peak = ((0,0),(100,9))
bounds_flat_top = ((0,7),(100,9))

# fit function
popt, pcov = curve_fit(general_norm, x, y, bounds=bounds_peak)

# calculate rms
rms = sum((y - general_norm(x, popt[0], popt[1]))**2)

# set data for curve plot
x_fit = np.linspace(-4,4,1000)
y_fit = general_norm(x_fit, popt[0], popt[1])

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
ax.plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but that is exactly what I did, have you read the question? The normal gaussian won't fit the signal correctly if it's too narrow, or if it's too flat-top.

Comment: @kalzso then post you peak/flat data or generated peak/flat data for test.

Comment: I can't because that is extracted from a livestream camera image. As you can see from the post, I mark the signal's maximum point as well (with a red dot). If I fit a normal gaussian to a flat-top signal, the max of the gaussian will be higher than the max of the flat-top signal, that is bad. Also it will cut down the edges of the flat-top, so we lose information there. I need to fit a function that resembles the original signal the best way possible.

Comment: @kalzso for flat you can define `a` parameter as `max(y_flat_top) `, see update

Comment: still cutting down the edges, information is lost there. I need a generalised solution that works for every type of gaussian not just for normal. See Gabriel's comment above, I think he is on the right track.

Comment: Looks better! When the signal is too peaked your solution is not too good, but I will accept your answer!

Comment: @kalzso you can try play with `differential evolution` do find lowest `rms` and best fit.

Comment: How do you calculate the bounds?